java processbuilder arguments with quotes on windows
In git bash i am running this command, which runs fine
./script.sh -s "run:3-20-1-10000;10000;" mq

I need to pass this exact command in git bash through java on windows
I am doing this
string[] cmd = {"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe", "-c" , "./script.sh"}
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
pb.cmd.add("-s");
pb.cmd.add("\"run:3-20-1-10000;10000;\"");
pb.cmd.add("mq");
File newDir = new File("C:\\..\\");
pb.directory(newDir);
Process p=pb.start();

It runs the script and  does not give any error but also does not give the desired result
My suspicion is that it is not taking "run:3-20-1-10000;10000;" correctly (with quotes). how do I achieve this ?
EDIT:
If I do
String[] cmd = {"C:\\..\\bash.exe ", "-c", "./script.sh -s \"run:3-20-1-10000;10000;\" mq"}
 p = pb.inheritIO().start()

I get
  unknown option
  10000: command not found
   mq: command not found

I also get that unkown option error when I remove the quotes and run on git bash manually
so based on that I think , it has to do something with passing quotes correctly

What if you get rid of the \" quotes?  And are you handling the error stream?

If you do p = pb.inheritIO().start(), do you see any error output?

if I do
string[] cmd = {"C:\\..\\bash.exe ", "-c", "./script.sh -s \"run:3-20-1-10000;10000;\" mq"} p = pb.inheritIO().start()
i get unknown option  10000: command not found mq: command not found
I also get that unkown option when I remove the quotes and run on git bash manually

What language is that? Doesn't look like Java to me. (It's String not string, you can't manipulate pb.cmd like that, etc.)

I am not adding the arguments separately now because when I do not escape quote it does not give me any error. so I think I should continue to debug the way in the comments

Comments are intended to improve the question, not as interactive debugging help.

Two typos with quotes in the question I assume: {"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe", "-c" , "./script.sh"}

Thanks. I corrected them. Any idea on how to pass arguments with quotes using processbuilder?

Assuming this question really is about the Java ProcessBuilder, then a) you don't need -c and b) you don't need to quote any of the arguments

in your last code (EDIT) use single quotes instead of double ones

As soon as I enter single quotes in any of the argument , it gives me too many character in character literal.

cmd = {"C:\\..\\bash.exe ", "-c", "./script.sh -s 'run:3-20-1-10000;10000;' mq"}  (double quotes are escaped by ProcessBuilder [Windows])

You are fantastic!! That worked. Please answer and I'll upvote

but I would also try/use cmd = {"C:\\..\\bash.exe ", "./script.sh",  "-s", "run:3-20-1-10000;10000;", "mq"}(as commented by g00se - no -c, each argument one String)

I tried something similar earlier . I can not split arguments because of the way code is written . If I do that , it complains about outofboundexception and missing $0 argument

In real bash List<String> cmd = List.of("bash", "script.sh", "-s", "run:3-20-1-10000;10000", "mq"); works fine for me
